# Does Angular2 enfore SSL pinning

Tags: angular

Is it possible to enforce SSL pining in Angular2? Either via the standard $http, or by replacing it, e.g. with https://github.com/jhaynie/request-ssl.

Comment: What specific problem are you trying to solve?